# InfoWindow Scroll doesn't work in iOS

Tags: ios, angularjs, cordova, scroll, infowindow

I have an app in Cordova, and I use the element `InfoWindow`.

In Android, the scroll works correctly, but in iOS, it doesn´t work.
I have read about it but I didn´t get the solution.

I tried to use the css with some properties like `overflow-y: auto;`, but didn´t work.

How can I fix it? Thank you!

Comment: If you share what you have tried so far (by adding your code to the question) and the reading you have done you will improve your question and may find more help with be forthcoming.

Answer (score 0):

Try to apply this css in iOS instead:

```
<!-- language: lang-css -->
-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
<!-- end snippet -->
```

I hope it will help.